# Problem with Calculating Tensorflow learning label

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using Tensorflow to train a neural network by gradually adjusting it's output based on the result of a physics simulation. The network works like this: I have a random noise input to a dense neural net, and the output is from a tanh activation, making a vector of a few numbers (6 in the example shown) between -1 and 1. I take these numbers and use them in a physics simulation, and based on the result I want to apply a small change to the output by creating a label for training which is produced by scaling parts of the original output. I have created two python example files which summarize the problem I am having.

For example if the output is:

`[0.8, 0.4, -0.3, 0.1, -0.9, 0.5]`

I will create a label by multiplying the original output by a scalar vector like this:

`[1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0] * [0.8, 0.4, -0.3, 0.1, -0.9, 0.5]`

```
= [0.88, 0.44, -0.33, 0.1, -0.9, 0.5]
```

And after running a train step using an ADAM optimizer to reduce mse error between the output and label (above), I expect to see the output, (given the same noise input) should have shifted to more closely resemble the label.

This is exactly what happens when I calculate the label from the network output and input the entire calculated label as a placeholder into tensorflow, and it works as I expect it should (CODE 1, below).

CODE 1 OUTPUT:

```
initial output: 
[[ 0.4489846   0.29872498 -0.6448472  -0.2561627  -0.26684356  0.5127055 ]] 

label: 
[[ 0.49388307  0.3285975  -0.7093319  -0.2561627  -0.26684356  0.5127055 ]] 

trained output: 
[[ 0.4666028   0.318578   -0.6672877  -0.25193644 -0.2668022   0.51966786]]
```

However, I want to input a single scalar value into tensorflow and have the label calculated in tensorflow by multiplying the scalar value to an indexed part of the network output (CODE 2, below), rather than calculating it in numpy and feeding the entire label in as a placeholder. When training with this method of creating the label in tensorflow, the network output consistently shifts in the opposite direction of the label, like this:

CODE 2 OUTPUT:

```
initial output: 
[[ 0.4517809  -0.48581237  0.0353935   0.19568376 -0.60063607  0.16790062]] 

label: 
[[ 0.49695897 -0.5343936   0.03893284  0.19568376 -0.60063607  0.16790062]] 

trained output: 
[[ 0.42061377 -0.46081907  0.02022755  0.1914451  -0.60077196  0.15687937]]
```

This doesnt make any sense to me, and I dont understand why this is happening

I'm aware this doesn't make much difference from a computational time/load perspective, but now I think I seem to have a misunderstanding of what tensorflow is doing to minimize a cost function, as I dont understand why calculating the label within tensorflow, and calculating the label externally in numpy and feeding it as a placeholder yields a different result.

So ultimately my question is why is the result of these two .py files (CODE 1 and CODE 2) different? They are nearly identical but CODE 1 inputs the entire label as a feed dict value, CODE 2 calculates the label in tensorflow based on a single value from the feed dict.

CODE 1 (feed entire calculated label):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def network(input):

    hidden1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=input, units=128, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    hidden2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=hidden1, units=128, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    output = tf.layers.dense(inputs=hidden2, units=6, activation=tf.nn.tanh)
    return output


noise_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, 100])
output = network(noise_in)


# placeholder is the entire label
label = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, 6])
# define loss
loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=label, predictions=output)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0001)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)


init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    random_noise_input = np.random.random(100).reshape(1, -1)


    # the initial output of the network
    out = sess.run(output, feed_dict={noise_in: random_noise_input})
    print("initial output: ")
    print(out, "\n")


    # define label
    label_in = np.array(out)
    label_in[:, 0:3] = label_in[:, 0:3] * 1.1


    # print the label
    out = sess.run(label, feed_dict={noise_in: random_noise_input,
                                      label: label_in})
    print("label: ")
    print(out, "\n")

    # train the network with this label
    sess.run(train, feed_dict={noise_in: random_noise_input,
                               label: label_in})

    # the output after the network is trained once
    out = sess.run(output, feed_dict={noise_in: random_noise_input})
    print("trained output: ")
    print(out, "\n")
```

CODE 2 (calculate label in tensorflow):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def network(input):

    hidden1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=input, units=128, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    hidden2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=hidden1, units=128, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    output = tf.layers.dense(inputs=hidden2, units=6, activation=tf.nn.tanh)
    return output


noise_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, 100])
output = network(noise_in)


reward_scaler = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[])
# multiply part of the output by a scalar value determined by the placeholder
output1 = tf.ones_like(output[:, :3]) * reward_scaler
output2 = tf.ones_like(output[:, 3:])
label = tf.concat([output1, output2], axis=1) * output
# define loss
loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=label, predictions=output)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0001)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)


init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    random_noise_input = np.random.random(100).reshape(1, -1)


    # the initial output of the network
    out = sess.run(output, feed_dict={noise_in: random_noise_input})
    print("initial output: ")
    print(out, "\n")

    # print the label
    out = sess.run(label, feed_dict={noise_in: random_noise_input,
                                      reward_scaler: 1.1})
    print("label: ")
    print(out, "\n")

    # train the network with this label
    sess.run(train, feed_dict={noise_in: random_noise_input,
                               reward_scaler: 1.1})

    # the output after the network is trained once
    out = sess.run(output, feed_dict={noise_in: random_noise_input})
    print("trained output: ")
    print(out, "\n")
```

Comment: Your problem seems to be that the computation of you label depends on the output of the network. So when minimizing the MSE of the label and the output, the backwards gradients flow not only through the output, as in your first example, but also through the labels. In the first example labels is a constant, in the second it becomes a variable, Hence you have to stop the gradients flowing through the labels. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stop_gradient

This should work
label = tf.concat([output1, output2], axis=1) * tf.stop_gradient(output)

Comment: yes, that works and now I understand. Thank you